# Javascript - Saving 2d Array to Local Storage and retrieving

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a two-dimensional array holding information which I need to save to local storage and then retrieve later. Here is my data:

```
var content_array = [
    ["0","Mobile Application Development","CT5006","01/14/2013","Note"],
    ["1","Java Programming","CT5005","01/16/2013","Note"],
    ["2","Multimeida Application Development","CT5011","02/13/2013","Note"]
];
```

Any easy way to turn this into a string then back into a 2D array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the native [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(content_array);
```

You can then use the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to get it back into an actual array:

```
var content_array = JSON.parse(str);
```